# Representing duplicate values in a chart

Tags: c#, sql, charts

I'm working with a basic chart in c# and I have come across a problem in my code whereby if I have a duplicate category in my table, with a different date, the category is duplicated in my table.

I think this could be solved in SQL rather than C# but i'm a bit stumped.

Here is my table:

[image: Table Design]

Here is my code:

```
if (selectedLocation == "All")
{

string selectAllQuery = "SELECT category, counter, date, locationName FROM categoryData WHERE locationName IN (@location, @location2, @location3) AND date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate ORDER BY locationName, category";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectAllQuery, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", startDate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", endDate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", "Front Desk");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location2", "Harold Cohen");
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    this.resultChart.Series["Footfall"].Points.AddXY(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetInt32(1));
    resultChart.ChartAreas["main"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

[image: Chart]

As you can see, if I have a duplicate category with a different date, the category is duplicated.  I'm trying to sum the values of rows two of which have duplicate values.

Edit:  Ive got a bit further and now I ca aggregate rows with common category but I want to add the counter up for each aggregated column.

```
SELECT category, COUNT(id) as count, locationName FROM categoryData WHERE locationName IN (@location, @location2, @location3) AND date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate GROUP BY locationName, category ORDER BY locationName, category
```

Comment: You should probably use a GROUP BY in your select, on the field "category", and then select the SUM() of "counter". But doing so, you can't extract the fields "date" and "locationName" as is. If you don't need them though, you can omit them

Comment: Ive found the solution and edited my code to reflect.

Comment: You should add: "SUM(counter) as Counter" in the Select list. That sums the counters for all elements in the group

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with Alex Zen.

Your query should return all values, but each row in the DB will be returned as its own result, because the program does not know what you consider the 'same category'. You can either add a GROUP BY in code (with linq) or in T-SQL and specify what you consider the same (in this case Category) and you should be able to sum up your totals for that category.

Comment: can you give me an example of using the group by statement, i cant get it to work.  Thanks.